# Set UINavigationItem title before viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

This is the point: I'm writing an app that "builds itself" reading a configuration file.
What I need to do is create an `UITabBarController` which contains several `UINavigationController`s with their respective `rootViewController`. Since the app doesn't know what will be the `viewController` titles, I need to programmatically set them (from the `AppDelegat`e) before the `viewWillAppear:` method is fired.

If I set the title in the `viewWillAppear` method, only the first v.c. in the `tabBarViewController` will show its name in the `tabBar`.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: what's stopping you from doing it in viewdidLoad?

Comment: Because until the respective tab isn't loaded (clicked the first time), the viewDidLoad method of the rootViewController isn't fired. So the name doesn't appear in the tab until that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on many assumptions about what you are trying to achieve, I think doing this in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your `AppDelegate` should work:

```
UITabBarController *cont = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<CONTROLLERS_COUNT; i++) {
    UINavigationController *navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    navCont.title = TITLE_HERE;
    [cont addChildViewController:navCont];
}

[self.window setRootViewController:cont];
```

Comment: Oh dear, you're right! Rightfully is the navController to be the one added to the TabBarController... Thanks!!